# Is Smullyans Axiom System P.E. correct?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, peano-axioms, incompleteness

Raymond Smullyan in his book on Gödel's incompleteness theorems introduces a certain axiom system for Peano arithmetic with exponentiation (PE, see below). He then shows that under the assumption that system is correct (i.e., all provable sentences are true for the natural numbers $\mathbf{N}$), one can prove Gödel's first incompleteness theorem.

Now I am wondering if one has to *assume* that this system is correct, or if one can *prove* this.

**The axioms of PE**
[image]

[image]

and the usual induction axiom

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "a system is correct"?

Comment: @Trebor I am pretty sure "consistent" is meant

Comment: Goedel's second incompleteness theorem at least shows why it is usually extremely difficult and probably sometimes even impossible to prove the consistency of a sufficient powerful theory. Gentzen used transifnite induction instead of a stronger theory to prove the consistency of the peano axioms, a widely accepted workaround. A stronger theory (containing the current one) cannot help since we run into a follow-problem.

Comment: The context of original Godel's researches that lead to the Incompleteness Th was exactly the attempts to prove the consistency of formal arithmetic.

Comment: @Trebor I meant correct indeed. Smullyan calls a system correct if all provable sentences are true (which, in his setup, probably means that $\mathbf{N}$ satisfies them).

Comment: @Peter Does Gödel 2 really mean that? Certainly, it says, arithmetic cannot prove its consistency, but does that mean I (who can do more than FOL) can't? Anyway, I don't think I am talking about consistency.

Comment: Sounds like you're referring to what is usually called _soundness_ and yes it is possible to prove.

Comment: Barring typos (I didn't proofread the axiom system carefully), all the axioms are true in $\mathbb N$ (with the usual meanings of $\bar0,{}',+,\cdot,E$) and all the inference rules preserve truth, so all provable sentences are true in $\mathbb N$.  (This argument can't be formalized in PE, but it can be formalized in the usual set theory ZFC and indeed in tiny fragments of ZFC.)